# How can I setup my environment to build my own ril library?

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

I want to modify Radio Layer Interface(RIL), but I just have the ril source and when I try to build my own binary of rild with NDK's toolchain (arm-linux-androideabi-4.6) I get a bug like this:

```
rild.c:27:27: fatal error: telephony/ril.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

How can I setup my environment, step by step, to build my own ril library?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your project is not able to find the request library. Have a look in this detailed tutorial:

- [Working with the Radio Layer Interface (RIL) in Android](http://afewe.wordpress.com/android-arm-development/working-with-the-radio-layer-interface-ril-in-android)

After following all the step, take care to double check if you have all the files visible to your project or properly set in your environment path.

Comment: This means that If I want to compile ril, I will need the android's source code?

Comment: You have to install Android SDK. Depending on the application you wish to implement, you might also need the Android NDK. And of course your case will also need to have the RIL installed. If you are using some IDE, then remember to make all the setups that your environment will require to have everything tuned.